# Resetting state in ngxs

Tags: ngxs

When I add some new data to my state, the new data does not appear in my log or DevTool Ui.

Is there a mechanism to reset the state so that the data will appear. It seems that the old data from some cache is still being shown.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide details (e..g sample code) to describe what you have done?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use this reset plugin; https://github.com/ng-turkey/ngxs-reset-plugin

It's an ngxs plugin, easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

In v3.1 there is a `reset` function on the store that allows you to reset state see the docs [here](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/store#reset)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an action to your `app.state.ts` file as follows

> The Action to reset the state

```
@Action(ResetAppState)
resetState(ctx: StateContext<AppStateModel>): Observable<AppStateModel> {
   return of(ctx.getState()).pipe(
      map(currentState => {
         ctx.patchState({/* enter initial/reset values here */});
         return currentState;
      })
   );
}
```

You must also add the action into the `app.action.ts` file as

```
export class ResetAppState {
  static readonly type = '[AppState] Reset App State';
}
```

Now you can dispatch the action in your `service` or `component` easily to reset the `NGXS` state as follows:

```
constructor(private store: Store) {}

yourMethod(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new ResetAppState());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For state reset I try to use "meta-reducer" concept via plugin (https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/meta-reducers), but I have trouble with re-initialize state to default value for each slice.